# speed up a function in R

Tags: r

I have a list of files in a directory with the extension *.tmp2.out*, I read these files using:

```
 files.rand = list.files(getwd(), pattern="*.tmp2.out");
 data.rand = lapply(files.rand, scan);
 names.rand = gsub(pattern=".tmp2.out", "", files.rand)
 names(data.rand) = names.rand
```

A `head` of how looks my data is the following:

```
str(head(datos.rand))
 List of 6
 $ A1CF : num [1:50000] 0.812 0.1 0.764 0.894 0.495 ...
 $ A2LD1: num [1:20000] 0.797 0.282 0.9 0.276 0.339 ...
 $ AASDH: num [1:50000] 0.359 0.22 0.246 0.717 0.454 ...
 $ ABCA6: num [1:40000] 0.571 0.182 0.349 0.623 0.661 ...
 $ ABCB1: num [1:40000] 0.58 0.667 0.322 0.42 0.156 ...
 $ ABCC1: num [1:60000] 0.161 0.12 0.321 0.672 0.571 ...
```

Then I want to split each list element in sub/elements of 10,000 each, to achieve this I have used the following function

```
 chunks = function(x,n) {split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/n))}
```

that basically split my list in a certain number of chunks (in the example, 10,000).

```
list.split = lapply(mylist, chunks, 10000)
```

An `head` of how looks my splitted list

```
str(head(ll.rand))
List of 6
 $ A1CF  :List of 5
  ..$ 1 : num [1:10000] 0.571 0.182 0.349 0.623 0.661 ...
  ..$ 2 : num [1:10000] 0.0155 0.3622 0.4234 0.1101 0.5237 ...
  ..$ 3 : num [1:10000] 0.459 0.458 0.306 0.914 0.124 ...
  ..$ 4 : num [1:10000] 0.448 0.679 0.244 0.671 0.132 ...
  ..$ 5 : num [1:10000] 0.798 0.722 0.411 0.451 0.717 ...
 $ A2LD1  :List of 2
  ..$ 1: num [1:10000] 0.904 0.42 0.602 0.412 0.689 ...
  ..$ 2: num [1:10000] 0.336 0.656 0.521 0.485 0.409 ...
 $ AASDH  :List of 5
  ..$ 1: num [1:10000] 0.0875 0.9899 0.1029 0.016 0.5908 ...
  ..$ 2: num [1:10000] 0.162 0.534 0.424 0.116 0.57 ...
  ..$ 3: num [1:10000] 0.2823 0.5986 0.0657 0.4611 0.456 ...
  ..$ 4: num [1:10000] 0.0213 0.0449 0.0451 0.4611 0.3269 ...
  ..$ 5: num [1:10000] 0.489 0.913 0.22 0.156 0.621 ...
 $ ABCA6  :List of 4
  ..$ 1: num [1:10000] 0.8346 0.0782 0.4264 0.3873 0.6083 ...
  ..$ 2: num [1:10000] 0.0817 0.6402 0.7748 0.7125 0.4967 ...
  ..$ 3: num [1:10000] 0.793 0.316 0.182 0.753 0.563 ...
  ..$ 4: num [1:10000] 0.52 0.483 0.597 0.792 0.516 ...
 $ ABCB1  :List of 4
  ..$ 1: num [1:10000] 0.8607 0.2928 0.2203 0.0141 0.6871 ...
  ..$ 2: num [1:10000] 0.168 0.5665 0.0958 0.7202 0.4807 ...
  ..$ 3: num [1:10000] 0.939 0.743 0.295 0.404 0.79 ...
  ..$ 4: num [1:10000] 0.0255 0.1296 0.4843 0.5932 0.6778 ...
 $ ABCC1   :List of 6
  ..$ 1 : num [1:10000] 0.67152 0.94983 0.90776 0.7092 0.00133 ...
  ..$ 2 : num [1:10000] 0.755 0.893 0.789 0.172 0.163 ...
  ..$ 3 : num [1:10000] 0.724 0.375 0.897 0.493 0.731 ...
  ..$ 4 : num [1:10000] 0.758 0.576 0.499 0.508 0.642 ...
  ..$ 5 : num [1:10000] 0.1936 0.0927 0.0889 0.4293 0.3606 ...
  ..$ 6 : num [1:10000] 0.387 0.612 0.29 0.608 0.422 ...
```

The next step will be apply a function (Fisher.test) to the first sub/element of each sublist, then to the second and so on, the code that I use for this is:

```
ll.rand.fis <- lapply(lapply(ll.rand, data.frame), apply, 1, Fisher.test)
```

My problem is that the step of splitting the data in chunks is slow and takes a lot of memory, any ideas how speed up this process??

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please supply a simplified example of your data. If all of your sublists have less than 100000 elements, `ceiling(seq_along(x)/n))` will always be a vector of 1s. It's not clear what you're trying to do, exactly. Perhaps if you describe this, someone would be able to suggest a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "speed up"? In your example, most of the time is spent copying the data from `mylist` to `list.split`. I think you should instead *process* each chunk at a time, and save only the results.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't benchmarked these functions against yours, but I recently wrote two chunking functions to divide a list of vector into groups of n, or n pieces. These were the fastest functions I could write for the task, outside of using Rccp. (I tested them against several alternative implementations).

```
group_into <- function (x, size) {
# groups x into chucks of size,
# unless too few elements are left

size <- abs(size)
if (size == length(x)) {
    list(x)
} else if (size == 0) {
    list()
} else {    
    lapply(
        seq(from = 1, to = length(x), by = size),
        function (lower) {
            x[ lower:min(length(x), lower + size - 1) ]
    })
}
}

chop_into <- function (x, pieces) {
# chop a vector x into pieces...pieces,
# if it's possible

pieces <- abs(pieces)

if (pieces > length(x)) return (group_into(x, 1))

average_size <- ceiling(length(x) / pieces)

lapply(
        seq(from = 1, to = length(x), length.out = pieces),
        function (lower) {
        x[ lower:min(length(x), lower + average_size) ]
    })
}
```

In terms of memory usage these functions are still bad, since most R objects are deep-copied when being modified. This is difficult to avoid.

These functions are unit tested to make sure the corner cases aren't weird, though I don't know how well they will work for your application. If you get any speedup let me know :)

Comment: Hi @RyanGrannell, when I run the command `ll.rand = lapply(datos.rand, chop_into, 10000)` I got the following error:
`Error in seq.default(from = 1, to = length(x), by = size) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument`

Comment: If you are trying to group into chunks of 10,000 then you need to use group_into (the other function chops the list into 10,000 pieces, not pieces of 10,000 elements). 

I'm not sure what's causing the error, but try this...

lapply(datos.rand, function (x) chop_into(x, 10000))

Comment: The same error @RyanGrannell, anyway I'll try your functions with other datasets and I'll report you